# Difficulties with extruding

Tags: faces, extrude

First, I would like to say that I am very new to Blender and I am not a native english speaker, so... you've been warned! ( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)

I don't even know what to google for to find a solution. I am having trouble extruding my cup's top face into itself - when I'm doing it, it starts to look... well, pretty awful compared to Andrew Price's cup in his tutorial. What am I doing wrong?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Are you trying to make the inside of the cup? If that's the case, all you need to do is scale down the bottom vertices, as it seems currently there's an overlap of the faces.

Comment: Intersecting faces are creating the wavy pattern. The reason the top is dark is that you are seeing the backfaces of the mesh. To put it simply - your cup is way too thin, to the point of being partially inside-out.